# Infinite loop while trying to determine the injectivity of a list

Tags: python, loops

For a school work, we have to create a function that determines if a list is injective, which returns True or False. 2 ways of doing the job are recommended : with 'for' loops and with 'while' loops. I managed to program with 'for' loops, but I'm having issues with 'while' loops, as i cannot figure out why mine is infinite.

I'll put my code below. I already tried getting rid of  few variables that where needless, and as I modify the value of 'a' within the loop, it seems to me there is nothing wrong on paper.

```
def injective(x):  
      i=0
      k=i+1
      a=True
      while i<len(L)-1 :  #L is the name of the list
           while k<len(L) :
                if L[i]==L[k] :
                    a=False
                else :
                    a=True
                    i+=1
      return a
```

I expect to get True when the list is injective and False when not

Comment: put k+=1 inside while k<len(L) loop and i+=1 in outer while loop

Comment: `L` is `x` or something else?

Comment: converting a `for` loop to a `while` loop would be an easier approach if you have that working. anyways, your innermost loop is never modifying the value of `k` so the condition never becomes false. as a tip, if you can do it in a `for` loop, make sure you convert each for loop to a `while` loop by resetting and incrementing at the right levels.

Comment: Thank you for the help I see what i forgot.

Comment: The title given to your question is unlikely to be useful for anybody searching for answers about a similar problem. The question not abot injectivity of a list, but about how to convert for loops to while loops. This already has answers on SO, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26522997).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the value of k in the inner loop is not changing, I think you are missing `k+=1` somewhere.

**Code**

```
def injective(x):  
  i=0
  k=i+1
  while i<len(L)-1 :  #L is the name of the list
       while k<len(L) :
            if L[i]==L[k] :
                return False
            k+=1
       i+=1
  return True
```

I have taken the liberty to optimize the code a bit (it will decrease your iterations drastically for a non-injective function). You can use the same in your other program with the for loop.

Comment: This is similar to what I have for my for loop, thank you for the help

Comment: One more thing, I am not sure why you need 'len(L)-1' in the outer loop, I think you will need to check the last element also. (not sure though)

Comment: Isn't the last element checked with the first iteration ?